Node Js. error al tratar de definir un modelo en sequelize:
Estoy tratando de crear una servidor Rest utilizando Nodejs, postgresql como base de datos y Sequilize...
al tratar de definir un medelo node me manda un error "TypeError: Sequelize.define is not a function"
La base de datos ya existe y las tablas esán pobladas, porque se utiliza con un servidorr Datasnap para aplicaciones de escritorio...
Este es el código;
Tengo el siguiente código: (index.js)`
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { pgConnection, pgSequelConn } = require('./database/config');

require('./models/cashflow.js') ;
// Crear el servidor de express
const app = express();

const puerto = 8082;

// Configurar cors
app.use(cors());
// carpeta pública......
app.use( express.static('public'));
// lectura y parseo del body..
app.use(express.json());

//Base de datos
//pgConnection();
pgSequelConn();


app.listen(puerto, () => {
    console.log(` Servidor corriendo en el puerto ${puerto}`);
});

un Controlador de dB: (config.js) :
const { Pool} = require('pg');
const { Sequelize } = require ( 'sequelize' ); 

const conecctionData = {
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'sico2021',
    password: 'sysadmin',
    port: 5432
};

// const pgConnection = new Posgres(conecctionData);
const pgConnection = async() =>{
    client = new Pool(conecctionData);
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Conectado a la base de datos');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error al iniciar la base de datos');
    }
}
const pgSequelConn = async() =>{
    const sequelize = new Sequelize (
        conecctionData.database,
        conecctionData.user,
        conecctionData.password, 
        {
            host: conecctionData.host,
            dialect: 'postgres'
        });
    try {
        await sequelize.sync();
        console.log( 'Conectado a la base de datos con Sequelize');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw new Error('Error al iniciar la base de datos con Sequelize');
    }
}

module.exports = {
    pgSequelConn,
    pgConnection
};

y un modelo: (cashflow.js)
const { sequelize } = require("../database/config").Sequelize;
const { Sequelize } = require ( 'sequelize' ); 

> Originalmente estaba usando:
> import { Datatypes } from ('sequelize') e import {pgSequelConn} from
> ('../database/config') pero me daba un error

const cashflow = Sequelize.define (
  "cashflow",
  {
    fecha: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    tipo: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    clasif: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    concepto: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    importe: {
      type: Sequelize.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    moneda: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    tc: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      defaultValue: 1,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    proyecto: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    cheque: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    captura: {
      type: Sequelize.DataTypes.DATE,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

module.exports = {
  cashflow
}

El error que en consola es:
const cashflow = Sequelize.define (
^
TypeError: Sequelize.define is not a function
at Object. (/home/hfernandez/aplicaciones/DiseAdm/models/cashflow.js:4:28)
ojalá me puedan ayudar, estoy atorado con esto.
ne he encontrado una solución en linea

No puedes llamar a define sobre la clase Sequelize directamente porque no es un metodo estatico, tienes que llamar a define sobre una instancia de la clase Sequelize. En otras palabras declara una variable const connection = new Sequelize(......) y usa define asi connection.define(....)
